# Adding row in table in xhtml document with jQuery 1.4.4 and Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, xhtml, html-table, row

I have to pass a web site from html to xhtml because in need to include svg.

Since this change, I can't add row in tables.

Environment : Firefox 3.6.12 with firebug, jQuery 1.4.4

Unit test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.addrowb").click(function(){
 $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>new row on bottom</td><td></td></tr>");
 return false;
 })
 $("a.addrowt").click(function(){
 $("table tbody").prepend("<tr><td>new row on top</td><td></td></tr>");
 return false;
 })
})
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a  class="addrowb" href="#">Add row In the bottom</a> <a  class="addrowt" href="#">Add row In the Top</a>
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Text 1</td><td>text 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `a` tags don't have the relevant classes. Could this be the problem?

Comment: your right, i fix the sample. but the problem is still here

Comment: works perfect for me in all browsers, can you set up a test page so I can check?

Comment: Is it just Firefox that demonstrates the problem, and **only** with jQuery 1.4.4?

Comment: It works perfect if file has html extension. it doesn't work with xhtml extension!

Comment: here a link to test: https://www.breizh-biniou.fr/~mathieu/shared/testjs/test.xhtml

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7WW/

Comment: Blowsie : my browser says : text/html and not application/xhtml+xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to externalize your custom JS.

for example, create a main.js in the same folder you got your .xhtml file in and put your custom code in it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.addrowb").click(function(){
 $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>new row on bottom</td><td></td></tr>");
 return false;
 })
 $("a.addrowt").click(function(){
 $("table tbody").prepend("<tr><td>new row on top</td><td></td></tr>");
 return false;
 })
})
```

Then, in your xhtml, instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.addrowb").click(function () {
            $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>new row on bottom</td><td></td></tr>");
            return false;
        })
        $("a.addrowt").click(function () {
            $("table tbody").prepend("<tr><td>new row on top</td><td></td></tr>");
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>
```

write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's working! thanks! 
embbeded java script is forbidden with xhtml? that's bad news for me ...

Comment: It's not forbidden but if you use FF and Firebug you can see the error. Launch your question's code, in firebug go in 'network', the (+) near your .xhtml and then the xml tab. You see that, the xml parser will try to parse what's inside the javascript which makes the js not working. Therefor, you can conclude that `append` doesn't work in pure xhtml if you append xhtml code in embedded js. External JS won't be parsed by the xhtml parser, so it's working ;)

Comment: @mruellan : If you have other pages with embedded js which doesn't have _xhtml_ or _html_ code in it, you can use it, else, use external file.